# Open file from a different folder in PHP

Tags: php, relative-path

Let’s say I have two folders in my PHP server root directory: `x` and `y`. There are two more directories inside the `x` folder: `a` and `b`. In the `/x/a` directory I have the `index.php` file and in the `/y` folder a `stuff.php` file.
From my `/x/a/index.php` file, I want to include the `/y/stuff.php` file. How do I do that?
My server doesn’t allow including files from other domains, so adding the full URL doesn’t work! 
Also, I’d like to know how to start a path from the root in PHP. I use `./blabla` from the index of my root and `../blabla` from directories in the root, but, unfortunately, `.../blabla` doesn’t work from 2nd grade directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access the root begin your path with "/".

If you want to go up one directory from where you are currently, e.g. from /x/a/ to /x/ you could use "../".

If you want to go back up two directories (e.g. from /x/a/ to /) you could use "../../" (rather than ".../" which you mentioned).

Comment: Sure it would, but you need the full file-system path reference, not the web-view. If your site is in `/home/sites/example.com/html` and your `a` and `b` directories are below that, then you have do `include('/home/sites/example.com/html/a/mylibrary.php');`

Comment: It's not my own server, it's a free host... When I access my FTP, I see the "public_html" folder... Only in that folder may I upload and work with.

Comment: Marc B is correct. It is very unlikely you are working from the server root. You would need to use the full path, which will be something like Marc B posted, this is called the absolute path.

Comment: Ah, in that case you are best using relative paths considering you don't know your full path. So use the relative paths I mentioned - "../../" to back two directories

Also, what Chuck Morris said below might be the relative path you are looking for.

Comment: So you're subliminally telling me to accept Chuck Morris's answer? You said the same thing and sooner than him... Anyway, I will stick to backing the directory.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn't accept the answer yesterday. I've had to go to sleep before the 10 minutes timer ended.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
include "../../y/stuff.php";
```